# ImportError: No module named pysqlite2 code from Programming Collective intelligence O Reilly by Toby Segaram chapter 4

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, collective-intelligence

I am using **python 2.7.8**. The which code which i am following is from Book name as **"Programming Collective intelligence O Reilly by Toby Segaram"** chapter 4: I dont know why this error is coming or writer has made some mistake? I also tried to find pysqlite2 but failed. Any idea why this is the problem coming?

here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urlparse import urljoin
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
import nn
mynet=nn.searchnet('nn.db')

# Create a list of words to ignore
ignorewords={'the':1,'of':1,'to':1,'and':1,'a':1,'in':1,'is':1,'it':1}


class crawler:
  # Initialize the crawler with the name of database
  def __init__(self,dbname):
    self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)

  def __del__(self):
    self.con.close()

  def dbcommit(self):
    self.con.commit()

  # Auxilliary function for getting an entry id and adding 
  # it if it's not present
  def getentryid(self,table,field,value,createnew=True):
    cur=self.con.execute(
    "select rowid from %s where %s='%s'" % (table,field,value))
    res=cur.fetchone()
    if res==None:
      cur=self.con.execute(
      "insert into %s (%s) values ('%s')" % (table,field,value))
      return cur.lastrowid
    else:
      return res[0] 


  # Index an individual page
  def addtoindex(self,url,soup):
    if self.isindexed(url): return
    print 'Indexing '+url

    # Get the individual words
    text=self.gettextonly(soup)
    words=self.separatewords(text)

    # Get the URL id
    urlid=self.getentryid('urllist','url',url)

    # Link each word to this url
    for i in range(len(words)):
      word=words[i]
      if word in ignorewords: continue
      wordid=self.getentryid('wordlist','word',word)
      self.con.execute("insert into wordlocation(urlid,wordid,location) values (%d,%d,%d)" % (urlid,wordid,i))



  # Extract the text from an HTML page (no tags)
  def gettextonly(self,soup):
    v=soup.string
    if v==Null:   
      c=soup.contents
      resulttext=''
      for t in c:
        subtext=self.gettextonly(t)
        resulttext+=subtext+'\n'
      return resulttext
    else:
      return v.strip()

  # Seperate the words by any non-whitespace character
  def separatewords(self,text):
    splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
    return [s.lower() for s in splitter.split(text) if s!='']


  # Return true if this url is already indexed
  def isindexed(self,url):
    return False

  # Add a link between two pages
  def addlinkref(self,urlFrom,urlTo,linkText):
    words=self.separateWords(linkText)
    fromid=self.getentryid('urllist','url',urlFrom)
    toid=self.getentryid('urllist','url',urlTo)
    if fromid==toid: return
    cur=self.con.execute("insert into link(fromid,toid) values (%d,%d)" % (fromid,toid))
    linkid=cur.lastrowid
    for word in words:
      if word in ignorewords: continue
      wordid=self.getentryid('wordlist','word',word)
      self.con.execute("insert into linkwords(linkid,wordid) values (%d,%d)" % (linkid,wordid))

  # Starting with a list of pages, do a breadth
  # first search to the given depth, indexing pages
  # as we go
  def crawl(self,pages,depth=2):
    for i in range(depth):
      newpages={}
      for page in pages:
        try:
          c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
        except:
          print "Could not open %s" % page
          continue
        try:
          soup=BeautifulSoup(c.read())
          self.addtoindex(page,soup)

          links=soup('a')
          for link in links:
            if ('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
              url=urljoin(page,link['href'])
              if url.find("'")!=-1: continue
              url=url.split('#')[0]  # remove location portion
              if url[0:4]=='http' and not self.isindexed(url):
                newpages[url]=1
              linkText=self.gettextonly(link)
              self.addlinkref(page,url,linkText)

          self.dbcommit()
        except:
          print "Could not parse page %s" % page

      pages=newpages


  # Create the database tables
  def createindextables(self): 
    self.con.execute('create table urllist(url)')
    self.con.execute('create table wordlist(word)')
    self.con.execute('create table wordlocation(urlid,wordid,location)')
    self.con.execute('create table link(fromid integer,toid integer)')
    self.con.execute('create table linkwords(wordid,linkid)')
    self.con.execute('create index wordidx on wordlist(word)')
    self.con.execute('create index urlidx on urllist(url)')
    self.con.execute('create index wordurlidx on wordlocation(wordid)')
    self.con.execute('create index urltoidx on link(toid)')
    self.con.execute('create index urlfromidx on link(fromid)')
    self.dbcommit()

  def calculatepagerank(self,iterations=20):
    # clear out the current page rank tables
    self.con.execute('drop table if exists pagerank')
    self.con.execute('create table pagerank(urlid primary key,score)')

    # initialize every url with a page rank of 1
    for (urlid,) in self.con.execute('select rowid from urllist'):
      self.con.execute('insert into pagerank(urlid,score) values (%d,1.0)' % urlid)
    self.dbcommit()

    for i in range(iterations):
      print "Iteration %d" % (i)
      for (urlid,) in self.con.execute('select rowid from urllist'):
        pr=0.15

        # Loop through all the pages that link to this one
        for (linker,) in self.con.execute(
        'select distinct fromid from link where toid=%d' % urlid):
          # Get the page rank of the linker
          linkingpr=self.con.execute(
          'select score from pagerank where urlid=%d' % linker).fetchone()[0]

          # Get the total number of links from the linker
          linkingcount=self.con.execute(
          'select count(*) from link where fromid=%d' % linker).fetchone()[0]
          pr+=0.85*(linkingpr/linkingcount)
        self.con.execute(
        'update pagerank set score=%f where urlid=%d' % (pr,urlid))
      self.dbcommit()

class searcher:
  def __init__(self,dbname):
    self.con=sqlite.connect(dbname)

  def __del__(self):
    self.con.close()

  def getmatchrows(self,q):
    # Strings to build the query
    fieldlist='w0.urlid'
    tablelist=''  
    clauselist=''
    wordids=[]

    # Split the words by spaces
    words=q.split(' ')  
    tablenumber=0

    for word in words:
      # Get the word ID
      wordrow=self.con.execute(
      "select rowid from wordlist where word='%s'" % word).fetchone()
      if wordrow!=None:
        wordid=wordrow[0]
        wordids.append(wordid)
        if tablenumber>0:
          tablelist+=','
          clauselist+=' and '
          clauselist+='w%d.urlid=w%d.urlid and ' % (tablenumber-1,tablenumber)
        fieldlist+=',w%d.location' % tablenumber
        tablelist+='wordlocation w%d' % tablenumber      
        clauselist+='w%d.wordid=%d' % (tablenumber,wordid)
        tablenumber+=1

    # Create the query from the separate parts
    fullquery='select %s from %s where %s' % (fieldlist,tablelist,clauselist)
    print fullquery
    cur=self.con.execute(fullquery)
    rows=[row for row in cur]

    return rows,wordids

  def getscoredlist(self,rows,wordids):
    totalscores=dict([(row[0],0) for row in rows])

    # This is where we'll put our scoring functions
    weights=[(1.0,self.locationscore(rows)), 
             (1.0,self.frequencyscore(rows)),
             (1.0,self.pagerankscore(rows)),
             (1.0,self.linktextscore(rows,wordids)),
             (5.0,self.nnscore(rows,wordids))]
    for (weight,scores) in weights:
      for url in totalscores:
        totalscores[url]+=weight*scores[url]

    return totalscores

  def geturlname(self,id):
    return self.con.execute(
    "select url from urllist where rowid=%d" % id).fetchone()[0]

  def query(self,q):
    rows,wordids=self.getmatchrows(q)
    scores=self.getscoredlist(rows,wordids)
    rankedscores=[(score,url) for (url,score) in scores.items()]
    rankedscores.sort()
    rankedscores.reverse()
    for (score,urlid) in rankedscores[0:10]:
      print '%f\t%s' % (score,self.geturlname(urlid))
    return wordids,[r[1] for r in rankedscores[0:10]]

  def normalizescores(self,scores,smallIsBetter=0):
    vsmall=0.00001 # Avoid division by zero errors
    if smallIsBetter:
      minscore=min(scores.values())
      return dict([(u,float(minscore)/max(vsmall,l)) for (u,l) in scores.items()])
    else:
      maxscore=max(scores.values())
      if maxscore==0: maxscore=vsmall
      return dict([(u,float(c)/maxscore) for (u,c) in scores.items()])

  def frequencyscore(self,rows):
    counts=dict([(row[0],0) for row in rows])
    for row in rows: counts[row[0]]+=1
    return self.normalizescores(counts)

  def locationscore(self,rows):
    locations=dict([(row[0],1000000) for row in rows])
    for row in rows:
      loc=sum(row[1:])
      if loc<locations[row[0]]: locations[row[0]]=loc

    return self.normalizescores(locations,smallIsBetter=1)

  def distancescore(self,rows):
    # If there's only one word, everyone wins!
    if len(rows[0])<=2: return dict([(row[0],1.0) for row in rows])

    # Initialize the dictionary with large values
    mindistance=dict([(row[0],1000000) for row in rows])

    for row in rows:
      dist=sum([abs(row[i]-row[i-1]) for i in range(2,len(row))])
      if dist<mindistance[row[0]]: mindistance[row[0]]=dist
    return self.normalizescores(mindistance,smallIsBetter=1)

  def inboundlinkscore(self,rows):
    uniqueurls=dict([(row[0],1) for row in rows])
    inboundcount=dict([(u,self.con.execute('select count(*) from link where toid=%d' % u).fetchone()[0]) for u in uniqueurls])   
    return self.normalizescores(inboundcount)

  def linktextscore(self,rows,wordids):
    linkscores=dict([(row[0],0) for row in rows])
    for wordid in wordids:
      cur=self.con.execute('select link.fromid,link.toid from linkwords,link where wordid=%d and linkwords.linkid=link.rowid' % wordid)
      for (fromid,toid) in cur:
        if toid in linkscores:
          pr=self.con.execute('select score from pagerank where urlid=%d' % fromid).fetchone()[0]
          linkscores[toid]+=pr
    maxscore=max(linkscores.values())
    normalizedscores=dict([(u,float(l)/maxscore) for (u,l) in linkscores.items()])
    return normalizedscores

  def pagerankscore(self,rows):
    pageranks=dict([(row[0],self.con.execute('select score from pagerank where urlid=%d' % row[0]).fetchone()[0]) for row in rows])
    maxrank=max(pageranks.values())
    normalizedscores=dict([(u,float(l)/maxrank) for (u,l) in pageranks.items()])
    return normalizedscores

  def nnscore(self,rows,wordids):
    # Get unique URL IDs as an ordered list
    urlids=[urlid for urlid in dict([(row[0],1) for row in rows])]
    nnres=mynet.getresult(wordids,urlids)
    scores=dict([(urlids[i],nnres[i]) for i in range(len(urlids))])
    return self.normalizescores(scores)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That book is eight years old, and refers to Python version 2.4. You've missed a step that will install the pysqlite2 module, but for versions of Python since 2.5 you don't need it: just do `import sqlite3 as sqlite` instead.

Comment: thanks. Error are overcome but nothing is happening according to the book it shd print score and link. But as u have said its 8 years old then what modification should i do to get those proper results?

Comment: i also found db from this link https://code.google.com/p/programming-collective-intelligence/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=9. i thought may be it could produce some results but no success.